# Before and After Contruct Method Class in PHP

Tags: php

cook looks like this:

```
abstract class Foo
{
     pulbic function __construct()
     { 
          if (method_exists($this, 'beforeConstruct')) {
              $this->beforeConstruct();
          }

      if (method_exists($this, 'afterConstruct')) {
          $this->afterConstruct();
      }
     }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function beforeConstruct()
    {
        echo 'Before Construct.<br>';
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Clas Bar has been created.<br>'
    }

    public function beforeConstruct()
    {
        echo 'After Construct.<br>';
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
```

but not working, somebody can help me? how to return results like this:

Before Construct.

Class Bar has been created.

After Construct.

Answer (score 0):

First call the `constructor` of the **parent** from the child class `constructor` , which in turn calls the method `beforeConstruct()` of the child class and after that it prints the `Clas Bar has been created.` after that it fires the `destructor` of your child class.

```
<?php

abstract class Foo
{
public function __construct()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'beforeConstruct')) {
        $this->beforeConstruct();
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'afterConstruct')) {
        $this->afterConstruct();
    }
}
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'Clas Bar has been created.<br>';

    }

    public function beforeConstruct()
    {
        echo 'Before Construct.<br>';
    }


    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo 'After Construct.<br>';
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

> ```
> Before Construct.
> Clas Bar has been created.
> After Construct.
> ```

Comment: afterConstruct is never called... it doesn't exist, i don't think is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Right , that is why I put it under a destructor.